# English Pronunciation of "Employé"

Tags: pronunciation

I've read a number of older books in which I see the work "employé" being used where we would today use "employee". The meaning in all cases was obvious.

Example:

"You seem most fortunate in having an employé who comes under the full market price."

(Source: "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes", Sir Arthur Conan Doyle)

How is this word pronounced? Is it pronounced the same as "employee" or is it pronounced as it is in French (I can't do IPA but, to approximate, something like "omp-lwa-yey")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site
[Etymonline "employee"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/employee)

traces "employee" to French "employé", the past participle of "employer", to employ, with a date of about 1850. Since Sherlock Holmes dates from about 1890, it's quite possible that the pronunciation of the borrowed, undomesticated form around that time would have imitated the French pronunciation, as you have indicated.
But, unless you're reading it out loud ...